# identifying a stock in a mix of stocks and applying numeric operations for the particular stock in reverse order

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Say i have a dataframe as shown below

```
   Stock     open     high      low    close          Avg
0   SBIN   255.85   256.00   255.80   255.90          Nan
1   HDFC  1222.25  1222.45  1220.45  1220.45          Nan
2   SBIN   255.95   255.95   255.85   255.85          Nan
3   HDFC  1222.00  1222.50  1221.70  1221.95          Nan
4   SBIN   255.80   256.00   255.80   255.95        255.9
5   HDFC  1221.90  1222.00  1221.55  1221.70  1221.366667
6   SBIN   255.85   255.95   255.70   255.80  255.8666667
7   HDFC  1222.00  1222.00  1221.45  1221.95  1221.866667
8   SBIN   255.80   255.95   255.70   255.80       255.85
9   HDFC  1222.00  1222.00  1221.25  1221.90      1221.85
10  SBIN   255.75   255.80   255.60   255.65       255.75
11  HDFC  1222.00  1222.00  1221.40  1221.80  1221.88333333
```

here is the link of the df i took screenshot off. https://photos.app.goo.gl/kTZERCerFzggDfHEA

Now the average column is the average of the previous three closes for that particular stock. How can i achieve this in python pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and `rolling`

```
df['Avg'] = df.groupby('Stock', as_index=False)['close'].rolling(3).mean().reset_index(0,drop=True)

df

Out[1]: 
   Stock     open     high      low    close          Avg
0   SBIN   255.85   256.00   255.80   255.90          NaN
1   HDFC  1222.25  1222.45  1220.45  1220.45          NaN
2   SBIN   255.95   255.95   255.85   255.85          NaN
3   HDFC  1222.00  1222.50  1221.70  1221.95          NaN
4   SBIN   255.80   256.00   255.80   255.95   255.900000
5   HDFC  1221.90  1222.00  1221.55  1221.70  1221.366667
6   SBIN   255.85   255.95   255.70   255.80   255.866667
7   HDFC  1222.00  1222.00  1221.45  1221.95  1221.866667
8   SBIN   255.80   255.95   255.70   255.80   255.850000
9   HDFC  1222.00  1222.00  1221.25  1221.90  1221.850000
10  SBIN   255.75   255.80   255.60   255.65   255.750000
11  HDFC  1222.00  1222.00  1221.40  1221.80  1221.883333
```

Comment: @ansev how would you achieve the result without `apply`?

Comment: I want to say as_index=False,  sorry

Comment: Can i use this on a existing dataframe where the Avg column is already present and any new entry with a stock name, say SBIN with new values of open, high, low and close only are added. Can i expect the Avg column to get updated automatically. As per what i saw in the net, the rolling is applicable for for dataframes which are complete.

Comment: @MichaelGardner - i tried your solution, but the new rows that gets added with only open, high, low, close is not getting updated with the avg calculation which we gave using rolling.

Comment: If you add new rows you need to execute the code again so that the values ​​are updated.

Comment: i had applied the logic and where after adding a row i execute the line again and its working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood from your df you are trying to calculate something like moving average metric.

To do this you can simply use for iteration:

```
for i in range(0, df.shape[0] - 2):
    df.loc[df.index[i + 2], 'AVG'] = np.round(((df.iloc[i, 1] + df.iloc[i + 1, 1] + df.iloc[i + 2, 1]) / 3), 1)
```

Where in pd.loc clauses you specify the columns on which you want to calculate the metric, I used own.

Also (if you want more specific metric) you can try to calculate an average using rolling method:

```
df['AVG'] = df.iloc[:, 1].rolling(window = 3).mean()
```

Instead of 1 you must use your columns on which you want to calculate the metric. In window column you specify the number of previuous columns on which you want to calculate this.

Hope this will help!